# Bulk update columns with Kendo UI grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've implemented a Kendo grid with basic CRUD functionality (JS front end, MVC controller) and this all works correctly. I have a requirement to provide functionality that enables a "replace all" type function. For example, I filter by a company name then click edit on a record and change the email address or phone number - I also need the option to update all records in the current filtered set to the edited email/phone number. (instead of editing each record individually).

Is there anything in the tool set enabling this type of functionality or will I need to build a custom control?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from a previous question, an example is here:

http://jsbin.com/alocoj/1/edit

Also if you require the filtered and sorted data set (instead of the entire set) use:

```
var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
var data = dataSource.view();
```

The `.view()` gets the current set